# Use a class field in the 'plugin.xml' for an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, plugin.xml

I am currently working on a little Eclipse plugin and I have to deal with the classic *'plugin.xml'* stuff, such as the creation of a nature:

```xml
<extension
    id="aplugin.natures.MyNature.NATURE_ID.id"
    name="Sample Project Nature"
    point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
```

Now in this particular example, I must, somewhere in my plugin code, give this *'id'* as a *String* to some Eclipse function. So I need to create a specific class like:

```java
package aplugin.natures;

public class MyNature implements IProjectNature {
    public static final String NATURE_ID = "aplugin.natures.MyNature.NATURE_ID.id"; //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

And **here comes my problem, I got some copy and paste of my *'id'***. I must admit that I am not very proud of it.

So my question is, does someone know a way to use the *'NATURE_ID'* field in the *'MyNature'* class directly in the *'plugin.xml'* file ?.

In the end I wish to write something like:

```xml
<extension id="${aplugin.natures.MyNature.NATURE_ID}" ... >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible by design.

The idea is that the Eclipse core can load the `plugin.xml` files for all resolved plug-ins/bundles without loading/activating the plug-ins. Resolving your construct above would normally require Eclipse to resolve all references for the class - `MyNature` in this case - which can easily lead to the activation of many other dependent plug-ins. Not good.

So - by design - all data in `plugin.xml` must be self-contained. (With the possible exception of localized strings).

Comment: That a shame, i often forgot to keep my id synchronized. Perhaps i could do the inverse of my question like grabbing the id by doing some xslt magic on 'plugin.xml' when the class's field is build. But it look a more dirtier to me.

Comment: And in order to pick out many of the IDs... you need an ID... :-)